# AS/400 create Journal JT400 (Java)

Tags: java, command, ibm-midrange

I would like to create journal for my physical file using java program.

a) How we can get the existing journal name and description by passing schema      name.?
   Ex: DSPFD FILE(SCHEMA_NAME/TABLE_NAME) command is executing successfully but no output in java console.

b) How we can read actual name of table and display in java console.

Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Test program to test the AS/400 Command from Java.
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String server = "SERVER1";
    String user = "USER_ID";
    String pass = "PWD_ABC";

    String getjournalcmd = "DSPFD FILE(SCHEMA_NAME/TABLE_NAME) OUTPUT(*PRINT)";
    String createjournalcmd = "STRJRNPF FILE(SCHEMA_NAME/TABLE_NAME) JRN(SCH_JRN_LIB_NAME/JRN_NAME)";

    AS400 as400 = null;
    try {
        // Create an AS400 object
        as400 = new AS400(server, user, pass);

        // Create a Command object
        CommandCall command = new CommandCall(as400);

        // Run the command.
        System.out.println("Executing: " + getjournalcmd);
        boolean success = command.run(getjournalcmd);

        if (success) {
            System.out.println("Command Executed Successfully.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command Failed!");
        }

        // Get the command results
        AS400Message[] messageList1 = command.getMessageList();
        System.out.println(messageList1.length);
        for (AS400Message message : messageList1) {
            System.out.println(message.getText());
        }

        // Create journal
        System.out.println("Executing: " + createjournalcmd);
        boolean success1 = command.run(createjournalcmd);

        if (success1) {
            System.out.println("Command Executed Successfully.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command Failed!");
        }

        // Get the command results
        AS400Message[] messageList = command.getMessageList();
        System.out.println(messageList.length);
        for (AS400Message message : messageList) {
            System.out.println(message.getText());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            // Make sure to disconnect
            as400.disconnectAllServices();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The IBM Toolbox for Java has a class to retrieve that information. [Here is the Javadocs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/FileAttributes.html). You are going to have to use the IFS name of the object in question which looks like this `/QSYS.LIB/libraryname.LIB/filename.FILE`

If I wanted to do this, I would try something like this:

```
String journal = "";
FileAttributes fa = new FileAttributes(myConnection, ifsPath);
if (fa.isJournalingStatus()) {
    journal = fa.getJournal();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you please share sample code.

Comment: Thanks, Very useful information. Also please let me know how to identify the actual file name (10 chars). Ex: T_EMP_INQUIRY_LIST have more than 10 chars, how to get actual file name stored in AS400.

Comment: You can use SQL to retrieve the table name from the system catalog file `QSYS2.SYSTABLES` the SQL name is in column `TABLE_NAME` the object name is in column `SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME`.

Comment: That is really a separate question and answer that should not be in the comments here.

Comment: Thanks you very much jmarkmurphy, how to find the list of open file in AS400 to journal.

Answer (score 0):

DSPFD output(*print) produces a report but doesn't return anything back to caller. You can use [QDBRTVFD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/apis/qdbrtvfd.htm) API instead to have the values returned back to the caller Java method. Alternative is to create a program on IBM i (AS400) backend that gets the information you need and has a simplified parameter structure.

Comment: Thanks for reply. could you please share me the sample code.